# como configurar URL amigables con subcarpetas

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda con lo siguiente

Estoy creando URL amigables en mi sitio web, tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas, una carpeta containers con un archivo llamado item.php y una subcarpeta shopping con su respectivo index.php

- /containers/item.php
- /containers/shopping/index.php

Las reglas que estoy usando en mi .htaccess son las siguientes

```
RewriteRule ^containers/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/item.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
RewriteRule ^containers/shopping/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/shopping/index.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
```

La primera regla funciona correctamente, pero la segunda no, al ingresar al siguiente link de ejemplo, me hace referencia que aun estuviera en la carpeta containers y no dentro de shopping

**http://implement.lc/containers/shopping/ECU-00002/ESP-5W-30-1L**

a que puede deberse este problema ?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la primer regla sobre escribe a la segunda

Answer (score 1):

La primera regla esta sobre escribiendo a la segunda regla

**Cambia**

```html
RewriteRule ^containers/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/item.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
RewriteRule ^containers/shopping/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/shopping/index.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
```

**Por**

```html
RewriteRule ^containers/shopping/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/shopping/index.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2 [L,NC]  
RewriteRule ^containers/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/item.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2 [L,NC]
```

También he agregado:
`[L , NC]`

**Donde :**

`[L]`  significa last :  es decir, en una lista de condiciones, no se leerán las condiciones debajo de la que tiene esta bandera

`[NC]` significa no case : solo hace que las comparaciones se realicen en modo que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Puedes Utilizar esta [herramienta](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) para probar tus htaccess