# URL amigable no funciona

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda con lo siguiente

Estoy creando URL amigables en mi sitio web, tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas, una carpeta containers con un archivo llamado item.php y una subcarpeta shopping con su respectivo index.php

/containers/item.php
/containers/shopping/index.php
Las reglas que estoy usando en mi .htaccess son las siguientes

```
RewriteRule ^containers/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/item.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
RewriteRule ^containers/shopping/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/shopping/index.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
```

La primera regla funciona correctamente, pero la segunda no, al ingresar al siguiente link de ejemplo, me hace referencia que aun estuviera en la carpeta containers y no dentro de shopping

http://implement.lc/containers/shopping/ECU-00002/ESP-5W-30-1L

a que puede deberse este problema ?

Comment: Es posible que la primera regla esté satisfaciendo también "shopping" como primer parámetro, y nunca llegue a la segunda. Intenta invertir el orden entre las dos y añadir [L] al final de cada línea (para que deje de aplicarse cualquier otra regla después de cumplirse la regla en cuestión)

Comment: La expresión " /([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/ " de la primera regla, como dice @Trekkium significa algo así como "letras o números de, al menos, longitud 1". Las letras serás mayúsculas o minúsculas, por lo que "shopping" encaja perfectamente en la primera regla.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como configurar URL amigables con subcarpetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/493179/como-configurar-url-amigables-con-subcarpetas)

Answer (score 1):

La primera regla esta sobre escribiendo a la segunda regla

**Cambia**

```html
RewriteRule ^containers/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/item.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
RewriteRule ^containers/shopping/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/shopping/index.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2
```

**Por**

```html
RewriteRule ^containers/shopping/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/shopping/index.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2 [L,NC]  
RewriteRule ^containers/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)$ containers/item.php?sku=$1&titulo=$2 [L,NC]
```

También he agregado:
`[L , NC]`

**Donde :**

`[L]`  significa last :  es decir, en una lista de condiciones, no se leerán las condiciones debajo de la que tiene esta bandera

`[NC]` significa no case : solo hace que las comparaciones se realicen en modo que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Puedes Utilizar esta [herramienta](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) para probar tus htaccess